# Call an object function returned by a method within php

Tags: php, class

There is any syntax to use something like this?:

```
<?php

function get_foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

get_foo()->foo_method();

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP 5.3 this works fine for me:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function foo_method()
    {
        print 'hi';
    }
}

function get_foo()
{
    return new Foo();
}

get_foo()->foo_method();
```

prints `hi`

Stuff like this is used all over the place for database wrappers since you can do `db()->query($sql)` without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

yeah PHP has this syntax, if a function returns an object, then you may call the objects property or method appended to the function's call exactly as it is in your question